# Перевод "Edit tags inline"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

[Оригинал:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

> You can...
>
> - Edit tags inline

[Перевод:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

> Вы можете...
>
> - Редактировать метки.

Не вполне точный перевод. [Например, я не понял](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23228885#23228885). Суть в том, что рядом с метками появляется отдельная кнопка, чтобы редактировать только их.

Предлагаю найти подходящий термин и уточнить перевод.

Comment: а «перевод» концовки предыдущего абзаца не стоит ли подправить? *вы будете помогать в управлении сообществом и служить пример* — «пример**ом**».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: пожалуй, стоит.

Answer (score 4):

- Использовать быструю правку меток

Answer (score -1):

- использовать встроенный редактор меток

Answer (score -1):

- редактировать метки на месте